# CloudWatch Agent alarms not displayed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have successfully configered CloudWatch Agent on a EC2 instance and can view the metrics in the "All metrics" section. When creating an alarm from these metrics, the alarm shows "insufficient data" and doesn´t display any metric.

The logs does´nt show anything suspicious.

The configuration:

```
{
        "agent": {
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "run_as_user": "root"
        },
        "logs": {
                "logs_collected": {
                        "files": {
                                "collect_list": [
                                        {
                                                "file_path": "/var/log/messages",
                                                "log_group_name": "cwagentlogs",
                                                "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}",
                                                "retention_in_days": 1
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                }
        },
        "metrics": {
                "aggregation_dimensions": [
                        [
                                "InstanceId"
                        ]
                ],
                "append_dimensions": {
                        "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
                        "ImageId": "${aws:ImageId}",
                        "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}",
                        "InstanceType": "${aws:InstanceType}"
                },
                "metrics_collected": {
                        "cpu": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "cpu_usage_idle",
                                        "cpu_usage_iowait",
                                        "cpu_usage_user",
                                        "cpu_usage_system"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                                "resources": [
                                        "*"
                                ],
                                "totalcpu": false
                        },
                        "disk": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "used_percent",
                                        "inodes_free"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                                "resources": [
                                        "*"
                                ]
                        },
                        "diskio": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "io_time",
                                        "write_bytes",
                                        "read_bytes",
                                        "writes",
                                        "reads"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                                "resources": [
                                        "*"
                                ]
                        },
                        "mem": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "mem_used_percent"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
                        },
                        "netstat": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "tcp_established",
                                        "tcp_time_wait"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
                        },
                        "swap": {
                                "measurement": [
                                        "swap_used_percent"
                                ],
                                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
                        }
                }
        }
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

BR,
Mark